# Proof of Hermitian adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, inner-products

How to prove that for any square complex matrix the following equation is satisfied?
$$
\langle \textbf{x}, \textbf{Ay} \rangle = \langle \textbf{A}^H\textbf{x}, \textbf{y} \rangle
$$

Comment: What are your ideas? What have you tried?

Comment: For complex column vectors $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ we have $\langle \mathbf u, \mathbf v \rangle = \mathbf v^H \mathbf u$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to simply write out the full sum.
$$
\begin{align}
\left\langle x, Ay \right \rangle &= \sum_{j=1}^n x_j \overline{[Ay]}_j
= \sum_{j=1}^n x_j \overline{\sum_{k=1}^n A_{jk} y_k}
\\ & = \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n x_j \overline{A_{jk}y_k}
 = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \overline{ A_{jk}} x_j \bar y_k
\\ & = \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \overline{A_{jk}} x_j\right) \bar y_k
= \sum_{k=1}^n [A^H x]_k \bar y_k = \langle A^H x, y \rangle.
\end{align}
$$